# Do both sentences have the same meaning?

Tags: sentence-meaning

1.He didn't run because he was afraid.

2.He did run not because he was afraid.

I want to know they are the same.

Comment: The second sentence is not grammatical in everyday speech. "did not run" and "didn't run" are equivalent; "did run not" is not idiomatic English, so it's hard to say what it means.

Comment: @SIS, does this sentence have any context or more punctuation? Could it possibly be, "He did run, not because he was afraid, but because of something else."

Comment: @Teacher KSHuang yes, punctuation is omitted to make ambitious sentence.

Comment: @SIS, I understand. So you want students to be able to identify the incorrect sentence.

Comment: @Teacher KSHuang yes, To get rid of ambiguous sentence I put it off here.

Answer (score 1):

The seconds sentence is ungrammatical if the meaning is intended to be the same as the first sentence.  However, there is a different meaning it could have.

The first sentence says he did not run.  The second sentence says that he did run.

The alternate meaning of the second sentence has a an implied "but", and could use a comma after "run":

> He did run, [but] not because he was afraid.

It would be a response to the statement, "He ran only because he was afraid not to run."

The "not" would negate being afraid rather than running.